# Do electronics distributers test each component before sending them out?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components

I'm trying to decide whether to order components direct from manufacturers in China or from distributors in the US. If I have to test each component either way, I'm not sure it matters to me if it's a knock-off or the "certified" one, especially when prices are 100x more expensive from distributors.

It's very important to me that my customer receives something that works and isn't let down either by a high price or a failure that could've been avoided.

Comment: Yes, this kinda gambling. I doubt they test in ONE by ONE. I almost sure they picked random sampling of each batch. 

As a seller, i recommend you to test each of it. You can claim your items as 1:1 - 100% working tested goods. For sure you can put this label with extra price. We see hand picked things, paired device (often in final transistor) usually have more price.

Comment: Please be aware of low-quality connectors. They might be looking good and all shaped as reputable parts (Molex, TE, etc.), but their plastic might be melting, and contact plating may not solder well. I just got a batch of such USB micro-B connectors, they sucks.

Comment: What sucks most is there are sure manufacturers in China which *could* make parts equivalent in function and quality to Molex, TE, etc., and I would happily design with those but there is much more money in counterfeiting and so Molex, TE, etc. (which manufacture in China, too) can charge prices like a pharmacy does just for kicking people's ass.

Comment: Yes, didn't you notice that every chinese part has a sticker QC passed, maybe more than one. At each process, they make a detailed inspection- as a proof, you may see them on the photos at Alibaba. Or did you get a product without a sticker on it? This could be the reason for malfunctioning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are talking about IC's, yes, manufacturers (not distributors) normally test 100% of the IC's as part of the production process. As far as I know, this applies regardless of country of manufacture. Distributors don't test anything. That is not their job.

Manufacturers may not test 100% of the features in a product, but they will test the product in some fashion. At a minimum, they will test each component on the wafer and discard bad components prior to packaging. (Wafer sort). The extent of post-packaging test probably varies depending on complexity of the product, etc.

I think it is relatively unusual for electronics products factories to test incoming electronic components prior to PCB assembly. You might have an acceptance test for things like speakers or LCD displays, but not for the components soldered to the PCB. If something like that is required, you would probably modify the design to exclude the troublesome part, or work with the manufacturer to improve outgoing quality.

It is certainly possible to be taken advantage of in China. But there are quite a few perfectly good suppliers of all kinds in China. Everything is built there, and there is a vast industrial supply chain in China. Taiwan is maybe one step up in quality and reliability compared with mainland China (PRC). But China is much bigger.

One thing you should DEFINITELY NOT do in China is buy major brand parts through gray market channels. There is a lot of fraud and counterfeiting going on. If you buy major brands, buy through authorized distributors only.

Comment: Kudos for *NOT do ... is buy major brand parts through gray market channels*. I have several friends who buy at AliExpress, and arriving chips are either not working, fry or just seem to be re-labeled (being other chips than declared). While buying there may seem to be cheaper, issue with components may cause damage to other components and will cause extension of manufacturing time.

Answer (score 3):

It is very unlikely that even a premium US distributor tests every component before shipping it.  And if they did, you would be paying an extraordinary premium price for the privilege. OTOH, ordering anything from Asia is even a bigger gamble.

That said, are you creating products from components (even pre-TESTED components!) and then not testing YOUR OWN product?  Depending that all the components are good and then blindly assembling them?  How do you know if your product is good even if assembled from good components?

Certainly, you can develop a sense of which vendors (foreign or domestic) deliver components with lower failure rates and adjust your buying preferences accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As a distributor yourself, you will be responsible for trace-ability to source and provide certs if necessary. You can pay other Disti's to test, but this is not normal practice, nor cheap. Thus you can request these certs or perform your own due diligence on supplier.

There is a huge network of 3rd party suppliers and from my meeting with many in this line of business and having personal inside sales experience from a Long Island office in NY, I can say,  that  Independent Distributors use a wide variety of sources, including independent Chinese suppliers.

http://www.erai.com/PartRiskMitigation

http://www.erai.com/ca_Counterfeit_Awareness_